# Xamarin Forms Syncfusion sfChart custom label for iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I have a stacked bar series chart created with Syncfusion for Xamarin Forms.  I need to show the data marker labels for some of the bar sections, and hide it for others.

Is there a way to customize the datamarker label to either change the color to transparent for certain values, or suppress certain values all together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have achieved this requirement using LabelTemplate in ChartDataMarker. In the converter of this template, we can check the requirement and return the null values when ChartDataMarker needs to be hidden.

Please find the sample in the below link.

[Sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/Simplesample-2074040717)

Regards,

Parthiban

Comment: The sample link is not working.  Also, will this work for iOS and Android in Xamarin Forms? Thanks!

Comment: I have edited the Sample Link. And yes, it will work on both iOS and Android in Xamarin Forms.

Comment: Is there an example of doing this without XAML?